# itextsharp paragraph chunk font being over written by list default font

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using v5.2.1 of the open source iTextSharp.  I have a section of code that is behaving not as expected. For some reason when I stream the pdf to the browser the font is different.

Below is a representation of what I'm trying to do.

```
Font times_roman = new Font(Font.FONTFAMILY.TIMES_ROMAN, 9f);
float indent1 = 20f;

try
{

   foreach (var item in List)  {

        Chunk c1 = new Chunk(string.format("Item: {0}\n\n" item.Name, times_roman));
        Phrase ph1 = new Phrase(c1);
        Paragraph p1 = New Paragraph(ph1);
        doc.Add(p1);

        Chunk c2 = new Chunk(string.format("(1) Item  Category{0}:\n\n" item.Category, times_roman));
        Phrase ph2 = new Phrase(c2);
        Paragraph p2 = New Paragraph(ph2);
        p2.FirstLineIndent = indent1;
        doc.Add(p2);

  }
}
catch
{
}
```

I then stream the pdf so it will open automatically in IE8 or IE9.

No matter what I try I always get the following results, no matter what font setting I put on c2, ph2, p2

```
Item: MyWidget1 (this dislays Times Roman)

(1) Item Category:  Utility Tool (this displays as Helvetica 12)
```

It’s as if iTextSharp considers it a ListItem because the of the (1) and is going to take control no matter what you do.

I cannot use Lists and ListItem because I only need to indent the first line and itextsharp lists will indent multiple lines and line them up automatically.  I have many items that have text that will wrap to half a page.

I really like the iTextSharp library (since it’s free) but this feature is driving me nuts.

Comment: I can guarantee that iTextSharp is not interpreting your text as a list and treating it differently, no such code exists for it do that. The code you posted doesn't compile, there's a lot of errors (missing commas, wrong casings, etc), please update your code and fix that. Also please include a little more context code such as the actual document creation and how you are writing to the stream. If you can, try to make your example something that anyone here can copy and paste into their IDE, maybe update 1 or 2 variables and have it work, that will help us help you.